# Is my linear mixed model ok?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, glmm

Hi I am trying to make a mixed model using `lmer` in R.

My model looks like:

```
m <- lmer(choice ~ I_D_gen + (A + B + C |sub), data = df)
```

My experiment design is:

- Independent variable: 6 conditions (2x3) with 20 trials each. A, B, C all refers to these conditions (including dummy coding). `I_D_gen` is a variable with 4 levels calculated by each endowment of each trial.
- Dependent variable: repeated measures of dichotomous outcome (0,1).

I am not sure if it is ok to build the model like this, because all the examples I see used models like below.

```
gpa_mixed = lmer(gpa ~ occasion + (1 | student), data = gpa)
```

I am asking this question because I am trying to estimate the sample size with the data above using the `simr` package.

Comment: Is your A, B, and C here belonging to a single factorial variable (such as Treatment A, Treatment B, and Control)?

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand Hi, my experiment is a within experiment with a 2 by 3 factorial design. 'A' refers to the 2, and 'B','C'  refers to the 3 (dummy coded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major issue I see with the code is that your outcome variable is binary, therefore you should use the `glmer` function with the `family=binomial` argument. If you model this as a Gaussian response, it will not make a lot of sense. Because you are also using what looks like multiple trials per person, you may also need to consider using a crossed random effects design like below, with random slopes chosen based off which factor variables align with their respective slopes (Page 7 of [this article](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v67/i01/) highlights when and where to code random effects):

```
m <- glmer(choice ~ I_D_gen + (A + C|sub) + (B|trial), data = df, family = binomial)
```

Generally speaking, if you have a random slope in your model, it should also be a fixed effect. You can't know the actual influence it has on the outcome without modeling it as fixed anyway. I will also add that the more random slopes you have, the more likely your model will not converge, and this will also be present in your power analysis. Consider a random intercepts-only model if you believe your data will not support a maximal model (correlated slopes and intercepts). This will often be the case when your data simply doesn't vary enough to warrant their inclusion as random effects.

I'm running short on time here, but it looks like your A, B, and C variables here are a combination of two factors. I'm guessing you are interested in each factor individually as well as their interactions. In that case it should be coded as fixed effects such as:

`factor_1 * factor_2`

Which will add the main effect of each factor as well as their interaction, such as:

```
m <- glmer(choice ~ I_D_gen + factor_1*factor_2 + (factor_1|sub) + (factor_2|trial), data = df, family = binomial)
```

Finally, I'm not entirely sure what the `I_D_gen` variable is by your explanation. You can clarify and I can amend my answer, but this answer tackles the main issues I saw with the code.

Comment: Wow thanks! I will try what you suggested. This helped me a lot. Just one more question, if I would like to know the individual beta coefficients of condition factors for each subjects, can I  try 
    m <-glmer(choice~ A*B*C + (A + B + C | sub)

Comment: What is your regression estimating if you separate them into separate variables? If you enter A into the model (let's say Control-Boy group) and only A subjects belong to it, wouldn't you be unable to estimate its variance? This variable doesn't change if all the same people belong to it.